# Uniqueness of non-degenerate critical point

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to show that if $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-degenerate critical point of $f$ then there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ containing no other critical points. I feel like this is connected to Morse's lemma but I am not sure of exactly how. Is it that if the Hessian of $f$ at $x_0$ is invertible then $f$ should be changing values all around $f(x_0)$?

Comment: Yes you are on the right track (with your last question). You don't need the Morse lemma, though.

Comment: Could you give a hint as to how to formalize my intuition?